# Big-O and not Little-O implies Theta? Similarly, Big-Omega and not little-Omega implies Theta?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, big-o

If `f(n) is O(g(n))` but not `o(g(n))`, is it true that `f(n) is theta(g(n))`?

Similarly, `f(n) is Omega(g(n))` but not `omega(g(n))` implies `f(n) is theta(g(n))`.

If not, can you provide an explanation/counter-example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NOTE : think of `O` as <= and `o` as <.

> If f(n) is O(g(n)) but not o(g(n)), is it true that f(n) is
>   theta(g(n))?

Yes, f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)).

```
f(n) = O(g(n)) means f(n) ≤ Cg(n). 

f(n) = o(g(n)) is possible if and only if f(n) = O(g(n)), but f(n) ≠ Θ(g(n)).
```

So, since f(n) is not o(g(n)), but it is O(g(n)), hence, f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)).

---

*NOTE : think of `Ω` as >= and `ω` as >.

> Similarly, f(n) is Omega(g(n)) but not omega(g(n)) implies f(n) is
>   theta(g(n)).

Yes, f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)). Following the similar logic :

```
f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means f(n) ≥ cg(n).

f(n) = ω(g(n)) is possible if and only if f(n) = Ω(g(n)), but f(n) ≠ Θ(g(n)).
```

So, since f(n) is not ω(g(n)), but it is Ω(g(n)), hence, f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n)).